# for /f Not Reading Text File List

Tags: batch-file

I can't seem to get my batch file to copy only the files listed in a .txt file.

Inside the source folder are three PDF files.
They are apple.pdf, bat.pdf, and cow.pdf.

The text file is two lines containing bat.pdf on the first, and cow.pdf on the second. There is no punctuation, spaces, or anything.

The batch, the list, and the two folders are on my desktop.

```
@echo off
set src=C:\Users\weasel\Desktop\source
set dest=C:\Users\weasel\Desktop\dest
set list=C:\Users\weasel\Desktop\animallist.txt
for /f %%F in (%list%) do robocopy "%src%" "%dest%" *.pdf /R:1
```

I want only the animals in the list to be copied, but the code is just copying all .pdf files it can find as if only the robocopy was there alone. I end up with apple, bat, and cow in my destination folder.

I seem to be messing up the "for /f %%F in (%list%)" part, but I don't really know this coding and I can't find anything online that dumbs it down enough for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included the metavariable in the list. `*.pdf` means "any file with a .pdf extension."

Try `%%F*.pdf` instead - or perhaps `%%F.pdf` if you file is `jaguar.pdf` and you want only that file.

Note also

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Use `for /f "usebackq" %%F in ("%list%")` to allow a filename containing spaces to be processed

Use `for /f "delims=" %%F in (%list%)` to allow a data lines containing spaces to be assigned to `%%F`

Use `for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%F in ("%list%")` to combine the two

Comment: Changed *.pdf to just %%F and it worked. Thank you for the quick response.